# ActiveMQ send ObjectMessage

Tags: security, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ to implement a messaging system in my current project. I need to send and receive Java objects instead of simple text or binary messages. The Java object (my message object) implements the Serializable interface as required.

Recent versions of ActiveMQ added some security and I need to set a property with the allowed packages as [described here](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html), but I haven't managed to make it work.  I'm not sure where that property needs to be added.

Error message:

> This class is not allowed to be serialized. Add package with 'org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES' system property

Comment: How did you configure the system property? Have you tried running bin/activemq.bat -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*" ?

Answer (score 13):

You need to either pass trusted packages in environment variable while running jar or you can do this programmatically by adding following line of code:

```
    System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES","*");
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

In your ActiveMQ config,add `connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("java.lang","your packagename"));`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class java.util.ArrayList! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload.